# Retrieve position of clicked ListViewItem

Tags: android, android-listview, listviewitem

I have a listview with items in it. Depending on which ListViewItem has been clicked I'd like to open an Activity and pass data to it. 
But how do I get the position of which ListViewItem has been clicked?

This is my code

```
public class tutorialActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tutorial);
        registerClickCallBack();
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.tutorialList);

        String tutorialTitle1 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial1_title);
        String tutorialTitle2 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial2_title);
        String tutorialTitle3 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial3_title);
        String tutorialTitle4 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial4_title);
        String tutorialTitle5 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial5_title);
        String tutorialTitle6 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial6_title);
        String tutorialTitle7 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial7_title);
        String tutorialTitle8 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial8_title);
        String tutorialTitle9 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial9_title);
        String tutorialTitle10 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial10_title);
        String tutorialTitle11 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial11_title);
        String tutorialTitle12 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial12_title);
        String tutorialTitle13 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial13_title);
        String tutorialTitle14 = getResources().getString(R.string.tutorial14_title);

        String[] values = new String[] { tutorialTitle1, tutorialTitle2, tutorialTitle3, tutorialTitle4, tutorialTitle5, tutorialTitle6, tutorialTitle7, tutorialTitle8, tutorialTitle9, tutorialTitle10, tutorialTitle11, tutorialTitle12, tutorialTitle13, tutorialTitle14};

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void registerClickCallBack() {
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.tutorialList);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked,int position, long id) {
            //How do I retrieve this position that has been clicked?
        }
    });
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare values outside of onCreate

```
String[] values;
```

then just assign a value to it:

```
values = new String[] { tutorialTitle1, ... };
```

and then in `onItemClick` get string using `values[position];`

And start activity depending on that string.

Comment: It is now `final String[] values` and in onItemClick I've put `values[position];` but that is throwing this error `values cannot be resolved to a variable`

Comment: Oh, yeah. Declare `values` outside of onCreate. In this case `final` isn't needed.

Comment: I don't want to return the string but the position, I'm trying to get an `integer` back

Comment: you can start your activity in OnItemClick. You have variable `position` there.

Comment: Ow okay I think I get it, I'll try it out and if it works I'll accept answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Use String selectedItem = (String) list.getSelectedItem(); to get selected String. Position of clicked item you have from method  public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View viewClicked,int position, long id)

Comment: But I don't know how to call that position

Comment: @mXX you not need to call this. You already have this position in method onItemClick. Try it for example: public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked,int position, long id) { Log.i("tag" "selected list item position - " + position); } This will print your selected list item position in log.

Answer (score 1):

Use getCheckedItemPosition() to determine the position of the selected item, assuming you have choiceMode:single.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#getCheckedItemPosition()

To simply get the position of the item that has been clicked in the onClick method, well that is right there for you already.

```
private void registerClickCallBack() {
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.tutorialList);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View viewClicked,int position, long id) {
            //How do I retrieve this position that has been clicked?
            int thePositionThatWasClicked = position;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking for, in the callback method you have position.

Answer (score 0):

Easy one. Reference here : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItemPosition()

```
getSelectedItemPosition()
```

:)